# React-Boostrap Carousel indicator not aligned

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm using react carousel with their demo code.
When I render the component, the indicators are not aligned properly:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwYCa.jpg

I'm not using any css at the moment so I dont know why this is occuring, except for the cdn included on the html page. Any help would be appreciated.

```
> export default class Home extends Component {  constructor(props) {
>         super(props);
> 
>         this.state = {
>             photoIndex: 0,
>             isOpen: false
>         };
>     }
> 
>     render() {
>             const {
>             photoIndex,
>             isOpen,
>         } = this.state;
> 
> 
>   return(
>     <div>
> 
>            <Grid>
>     <Row >
>       <Col md={6} md={12}>
>         <Carousel>
>     <Carousel.Item >
>      <img   src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7c0dpVFdGbGl0MWs"/>
> 
>     </Carousel.Item>
>     <Carousel.Item >
>       <img  src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7MVAySV9jME9TWWM"/>
> 
>     </Carousel.Item>
>     <Carousel.Item >
>       <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7N250S3JicmxxNmM"/>
> 
>     </Carousel.Item>
>         <Carousel.Item >
>       <img   src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7MDF5Vm1VYWhoY3M"/>
> 
>     </Carousel.Item>
>         <Carousel.Item >
>       <img  src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7X1ROMUxRMjVsN00"/>
>  
>     </Carousel.Item>   </Carousel> </Col> </Row> </Grid>
> 
> <Grid>   <Row>    <Col md={6} md={4} className={styles.topImage}>
>       <img src="http://placehold.it/291x363" onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: true })} />
>       {isOpen &&
>                     <Lightbox
>                         mainSrc={images[photoIndex]}
>                         nextSrc={images[(photoIndex + 1) % images.length]}
>                         prevSrc={images[(photoIndex + images.length - 1) % images.length]}
> 
>                         onCloseRequest={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}
>                         onMovePrevRequest={() => this.setState({
>                             photoIndex: (photoIndex + images.length - 1) % images.length,
>                         })}
>                         onMoveNextRequest={() => this.setState({
>                             photoIndex: (photoIndex + 1) % images.length,
>                         })}
>                     />
>                 }
>     </Col>   </Row>
> 
> 
> </Grid> </div>
> 
> 
>     ) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `img` tags should have `height` and `width` specified like so

```
<img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src="/assets/carousel.png"/>
```

This `width` and `height` should be equal to the carousel dimensions.

Comment: I have added the width and height to the img tag, but I'm still getting the same results

Comment: Could you post a Fiddle or something?